# are low poly games easy to create in unity 5?

Tags: unity, 3d-modeling

I am a beginner in unity. I saw few 3d games created in it. Developers tried a lot to make those games look good in free edition  but its hard to create eye crushing graphics at unity free edition. 
So, I choosed low poly graphics for creating my game ( it looks better than other unity graphics).
Is low poly graphics/models easier than creating normal 3d graphics/models in unity?

Comment: People create low-poly games, because they don't have the budget to create high-res model

Comment: And Unity isn't a modelling program

Comment: I'd quibble with the notion that it's hard to make games with good-looking 3D graphics in Unity's free edition. My last Unity game frequently gets praise for its photorealistic graphics (choosing a simple set of objects helped). Making a good-looking game in general is hard, but Unity gives you all the key features you need. The hard part is in the art direction, asset creation, and bringing all the features together to make a consistent expression of your style - no engine can just give you that. You need to be willing to put in the elbow grease yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity, UE4, Cryengine, Lumberyard - game engines. Blender, Maya, 3DMax, ZBrush - modeling, rigging, animating, texturing programs.

From my experience low poly is hard. Yeah, the models and their texturing are easier to create in some way, but modeling and texturing something really good - even in low poly is very hard. Low poly has its own style and feel in every game. It's not just a bunch of low polygonal models.

Anyway, creating a game with low poly graphics is not much easier from creating a game with high poly. Actually, there is no difference. You still have to code, rig, texture and animate. It takes less time to make some good looking low-poly models when you know how to make it right.

Despite everything I said before, It's much easier to start creating games with low poly graphics. Don't mix what I said, I meant: low poly is easier to create and texture, but the right and cool low poly is hard.

Also, rendering in Unity personal edition is not different from paid edition. All features that can be implemented in games are the same for both editions. Just the skill of creator matters. You can look differences yourself here https://store.unity.com/ . If you think that image effects are available only in pro edition - you are wrong. Those are just shaders and scripts that you can even write yourself, though there are plenty of them on the Assetstore.

Comment: And it's never easy to create game that will sell. If you want to create good games you have to work hard. There is no easy way anywhere.